# Writing Byte Array To Binary File Javascript

Tags: javascript, binaryfiles, binary-data

I am trying to write a script that generates random numbers these number then are converted to groups of 4Bytes each then these 4-bytes-groups are put into an Uint8Array finally I try to save the array to binary file. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Raandom Number Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="filesaver.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        if (!Date.now) {
            Date.now = function() {
                return new Date().getTime();
            };
        }

        alert("started");
        var currentMousePos = {
            x : -1,
            y : -1
        };
        var randomData = [];
        var bytes = new Int8Array(4);

        $(document).mousemove(function(event) {

            if(randomData.length>=1231){
                $(document).unbind('mousemove');
                console.log("Finished generating numbers ... trying to save file");
                randomData = new Uint8Array(randomData);
                var blob = new Blob(randomData, {type: "application/octet-stream"});
                saveAs(blob, "rand.bin");
                return;
            }
            currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
            currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
            var longRandomNumber = Date.now() * (event.pageX + 1)
                    * (event.pageY + 1);
            for ( var i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
                bytes[i] = longRandomNumber & (255);
                longRandomNumber = longRandomNumber >> 8
            }
            for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                randomData.push(bytes[i]);
            }
            console.log(randomData.length);
        });
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the generated file contains numbers `plain numbers` for example an element in the Uint8Array may be 65, in my understanding to binary this value should be saved as capital letter **A** but it is stored as **65** instead

***Note***

filesaver.min.js is a library that I use to save files from JS ([Link on GitHub](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Blob` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.Blob) does expect an *array* of typed arrays to be concatenated, but you are passing only a single `Uint8Array` into it. This will probably be interpreted as (should I say, "casted to"?) an array of DOM-strings - that's where your numbers are coming from.

A quickfix would be to use

```
new Blob([randomData], {type: "application/octet-stream"})
//       ^          ^
```

but I would suggest to either do

```
var randomData = [];
// while randomData.length < 308
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(4);
    for (var i=4; i--; ) {
        bytes[i] = longRandomNumber & (255);
        longRandomNumber = longRandomNumber >> 8
    }
    randomData.push(bytes);

var blob = new Blob(randomData, {type: "application/octet-stream"});
```

or not use those 4-byte `bytes` arrays at all:

```
var randomData = new Uint8Array(1232),
    count = 0;
// while count < randomData.length
    for (var i=4; i--; ) {
        randomData[count++] = longRandomNumber & (255);
        longRandomNumber = longRandomNumber >> 8
    }

var blob = new Blob([randomData], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
```