# use JavaScript to create a .mat file

Tags: javascript, html, matlab, export

I am developing a plug-in (for Grafana,an open platform for analytics and monitoring, https://grafana.com/) and to make data analysis easier, I want to enable the user of the plug-in to download a .mat file directly from Grafana. However, I am not able to create a proper .mat file in my JavaScript code. I have tried the following:

```
<button onclick="download('file text', 'myfilename.mat', 'text/plain')"><a href="" 
id="a">click here to download your file</a>Create file</button>
<script>
    function download(text, name, type) {
        var a = document.getElementById("a");
        var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.download = name;
        }
</script>
```

From [JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file). However, the .mat file that is created this way gives the errors:

Error using load
Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file C:\Users\Esmee\Downloads\myfilename (2).mat
"file".

Error in uiimport/runImportdata (line 459)
                    datastruct = load('-ascii', fileAbsolutePath);

Error in uiimport/gatherFilePreviewData (line 427)
        [datastruct, textDelimiter, headerLines]= runImportdata(fileAbsolutePath, type);

Error in uiimport (line 244)
    gatherFilePreviewData(fileAbsolutePath);

I have no idea what to do with this. I think the problem is that simply putting the string 'file text' in a .mat file is not the file syntax that MATLAB normally uses. Does anyone have experience with creating a .mat file with Javascript/html, or does someone know in what format this file should be made in order to be readable in MATLAB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just as a side note: MATLAB can read quite a lot more stuff than .mat. Have you considered storing the data somehow else?

Comment: You can use python to [save mat-files](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html). Perhaps this can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

MAT-files store date in binary form.

The MathWorks has published the file format specification [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf).

You could try to format your data (in accordance with the specification) in a single Uint8Array and pass that to the [Blob constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob). See the accepted answer to [this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244126/writing-byte-array-to-binary-file-javascript).